# Issues getting both tests passing and a coverage report with JMockit and Java 8

Tags: java, jmockit, junit5

I've been running into a lot of issues trying to get this working. I'm just trying to run a basic set of tests and generate a coverage report with JMockit. This is for a class and the purpose is to just make sure we can run it, so I didn't even write the tests, the professor did. After having a lot of issues getting JMockit to work at all, I now have the tests passing (which use mocks), but the coverage report is not being generated if I use JMockit 1.43. If I use 1.38, all the tests fail, but I do get the coverage report. I have used both JDK 8 and JDK 11, doesn't seem to give me any different error. I am not using Maven. Per my prof's request, I am using eclipse. Tests are written in JUnit 5.

Here are my VM arguments (for 1.38, but the only thing that I've been changing is to 1.43):

```
-javaagent:/path/to/jmockit-1.38.jar
-Djmockit-coverage-output=html
-Djmockit-coverage-metrics=line,path
-Dlog4j.configurationFile=./conf/log4j-file-config.xml 
-Djmockit-coverage-excludes=sun.jvmstat.*
```

Again, not getting a bug with 1.43 (just no coverage report is generating), but here is the bug that I get when I use 1.38:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: class redefinition failed: attempted to change the class NestHost or NestMembers attribute
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.redefineClasses0(Native Method)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.redefineClasses(InstrumentationImpl.java:193)
    at mockit.internal.startup.Startup.redefineMethods(Startup.java:171)
    at mockit.internal.state.MockFixture.redefineClasses(MockFixture.java:165)
    at mockit.internal.expectations.mocking.BaseTypeRedefinition.applyClassRedefinition(BaseTypeRedefinition.java:238)
    at mockit.internal.expectations.mocking.BaseTypeRedefinition.redefineClass(BaseTypeRedefinition.java:231)
    at mockit.internal.expectations.mocking.BaseTypeRedefinition.redefineClassAndItsSuperClasses(BaseTypeRedefinition.java:202)
    at mockit.internal.expectations.mocking.BaseTypeRedefinition.redefineMethodsAndConstructorsInTargetType(BaseTypeRedefinition.java:188)
    at mockit.internal.expectations.mocking.BaseTypeRedefinition.redefineTargetClassAndCreateInstanceFactory(BaseTypeRedefinition.java:271)
    at mockit.internal.expectations.mocking.BaseTypeRedefinition.redefineType(BaseTypeRedefinition.java:70)
    at mockit.internal.expectations.mocking.TypeRedefinition.redefineType(TypeRedefinition.java:29)
    at mockit.internal.expectations.mocking.FieldTypeRedefinitions.redefineFieldType(FieldTypeRedefinitions.java:82)
    at mockit.internal.expectations.mocking.FieldTypeRedefinitions.redefineFieldType(FieldTypeRedefinitions.java:68)
    at mockit.internal.expectations.mocking.FieldTypeRedefinitions.redefineFieldTypes(FieldTypeRedefinitions.java:55)
    at mockit.internal.expectations.mocking.FieldTypeRedefinitions.(FieldTypeRedefinitions.java:34)
    at mockit.integration.internal.TestRunnerDecorator.handleMockFieldsForWholeTestClass(TestRunnerDecorator.java:153)
    at mockit.integration.junit5.JMockitExtension.postProcessTestInstance(JMockitExtension.java:55)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$3(ClassTestDescriptor.java:215)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.JupiterTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(JupiterTestDescriptor.java:141)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$4(ClassTestDescriptor.java:215)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1654)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassTestDescriptor.java:214)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassTestDescriptor.java:196)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$0(ClassTestDescriptor.java:185)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$1(ClassTestDescriptor.java:189)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$2(ClassTestDescriptor.java:188)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:81)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:58)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.prepare(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:89)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:74)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$2(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.lambda$executeRecursively$3(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:120)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SingleTestExecutor.executeSafely(SingleTestExecutor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.executeRecursively(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor$NodeExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:79)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:43)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:170)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:154)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
```

Comment: JMockit 1.38 doesn't have support for the new "NestHost" and "NestMembers" classfile attributes, which were introduced in Java 11; support was added in 1.43.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switched to Java 9 (what the prof was using, even though it's unsupported), jmockit-1.38, and these VM arguments and it works:

```
-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf
-Djmockit-coverage-metrics=line,path
-Djmockit-coverage-output=html
-Djmockit-coverage-srcDirs=src/main/java
-Dlog4j.configurationFile=./conf/log4j-file-config.xml 
-Djmockit-coverage-excludes=sun.jvmstat.*
```

Still not sure how to get it to work using either 8 or 11 (and either jmockit version).

Comment: This should work on JDK 1.8 as well (minus the "-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf", which is JDK 1.9-specific).